# What happens if a Kubernetes pod exceeds its memory resources 'limit'?

Tags: kubernetes

There's a bit of a vagueness in the Kubernetes documentation about what happens if a pod's memory footprint increases to a point where it exceeds the value specified under `resources.limits`.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-limits-are-run

It specifies that if a pod's footprint grows to exceed its `limits` value, it "might be" terminated. What does the "might be" mean? What conditions would result in it being terminated vs which ones would allow it to continue on as-is?

Comment: AFAIK you'll experience pods OOM killed and thus stopped. Now if you're referring to request limits simply pods will be evicted and won't be able to be scheduled

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Q: What happens if a Kubernetes pod exceeds its memory resources 'limit'?

It will be restarted.

> Unlike Pod eviction, if a Pod container is OOM killed, it may be restarted by the  `kubelet`  based on its  `RestartPolicy`.

You can [Configure Out Of Resource Handling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/) for your `Node`.

> #### Evicting end-user Pods
>
> If the  `kubelet`  is unable to reclaim sufficient resource on the node,  `kubelet`  begins evicting Pods.
>
> The  `kubelet`  ranks Pods for eviction first by whether or not their usage of the starved resource exceeds requests, then by  [Priority](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/), and then by the consumption of the starved compute resource relative to the Pods’ scheduling requests.

Comment: Restarted how?  Does the kubelet turn down the pod and restart it, or does the Linux kernel OOM killer forcefully SIGKILL it?  What if the kubelet still has enough memory, but the pod limit is reached?

Comment: @SineSwiper: It has 5 stages: 1) The pod state is set to "Terminating" and it will stop receiving request, 2) preStop Hook is called, 3) SIGTERM is sent to pod, 4) k8s waits during grace period, 5) SIGKILL is sent: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace

Comment: I know how the Kube termination lifecycle works.  But, memory limits are governed by Linux cgroups, and when cgroups run out of memory, it's very similar to an OOM kill.  There's nothing left to terminate at that point.  At best, you have a pod with a dead, SIGKILL'd container.

Comment: It is indeed what I experience when my pod reaches it's memory limit. The pod is killed without any grace period, then restarted by k8s. I would expect starting a new container and then terminating old... If the killing is done by OS based on cgroups, then there's nothing k8s can do to improve availability.

Comment: So just to be a bit more accurate - the CRI is responsible for creating containers, usually via cgroups. cgroups have a "memory.oom_control" pseudo-file which determines if a process is going beyond its memory limits gets killed or not. While it's true that most (if not all) CRIs choose to kill such processes (for good reasons), it's not technically guaranteed and is CRI-dependent.

Comment: @MaBekistur Are you saying that CRIs might or might not set the memory.oom_control to be 1 ( do not kill ) or 0 ( kill ). And that kernal ( *not* kublet )  will kill the container later on *only* if the settings was 0 (kill)?

Answer (score 1):

Limits refers to memory and cpu.
If memory consumption increases it will be terminated but in case of CPU, os can allow tiny time slices to consume more than allowed CPU share.